# Show that $\neg$ and $\wedge$ form a functionally complete collection of logical operators.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Earlier this day I ask about the assignmet:

Show that $\neg$ and $\wedge$ form a functionally complete collection of logical operators.

I was given the hint that I could use De Morgan law to show that $p \vee q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$.

$$\neg (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \equiv \neg (\neg p) \vee \neg (\neg q)$$

$$\neg (\neg p) \vee \neg (\neg q) \equiv p \vee q$$

But I cannot figure out? am I done?

Comment: Whether you're done or not depends on what facts you already have. For instance, do you know that $\{\neg, \land, \lor\}$ is complete?

Comment: No, you are not done. You need to show that you can express *any* function $F:\{T,F\}^n \rightarrow \{T, F\}$ for $n>0$ in terms of the given truth functions.

Comment: Maybe I have to study what "functionally complete collection of logical operators" means

Comment: @AlimTeacher: If you don't know _that_, you certainly can't hope to prove anything about it until you have found out what it means.

Answer (score 3):

You may or may not be done, depending on whether you already know that $\{{\neg},{\land},{\lor}\}$ is a functionally complete collection.

If you *do* know that, you can reason as follows: Suppose we're given some truth function. Express it as an expression that uses $\neg$, $\land$, and $\lor$ (you already know this can be done). Rewrite every $\lor$ in that expression using the proof you already have. The result is an expression for the function that uses only $\neg$ and $\land$.

On the other hand, if you *don't* know that $\{{\neg},{\land},{\lor}\}$ is complete, then you're not done yet. Your best bet is to know *some* complete set and show that every function in that set can be made from your selection of operators.

If you don't know *any* complete sets of connectives, you have to start from scratch and find a proof that for every possible truth table of $n$ inputs can be realized by some expression that uses only $\neg$ and $\land$. (Or perhaps you can show some larger set to be complete, and then use that as a stepping stone to $\{{\neg},{\land}\}$ being complete.

Answer (score 1):

To show if an operator set is **functionally complete** you can use Post's 5 criteria from his 1921 thesis.

1) Easy to understand yet must log into Scribd unfortunately. 
https://www.scribd.com/document/255983069/Posts-Criterion

2) A little more difficult to follow but more rigorous. Pdf is readily available:
https://sites.ualberta.ca/~francisp/Phil428/Phil428.11/PostPellMartin.pdf

The five properties are that a Boolean function $f$ may have are:

- $f$ preserves zero $(T_0)$,
- $f$ preserves one $(T_1)$,
- $f$ is linear $(L)$,
- $f$ is monotone $(M)$,
- $f$ is self-dual $(S)$.

Post's Completeness Theorem may be stated as follows (This is straight from the first reference):

**Theorem.** *A system of Boolean functions is functionally complete if and only if this system does not entirely belong to any of $T_0$, $T_1$, $L$, $M$, $S$.*

This means that

- at least one function that does not preserve zero (i.e. it is not in $T_0$), and
- at least one function that does not preserve one (i.e. it is not in $T_1$), and
- at least one function that is not linear (i.e. it is not in L), and
- at least one function that is not monotone (i.e. it is not in M), and
- at least one function that is not self-dual (i.e. it is not in S).

The aforementioned documents spell these out in great detail so I will not belabor the point here. Post's Completeness Theorem, however, states that a functionally complete operator set is a set of operators which at least one function $f$ of the set does not entirely below to all of these sets 1 through 5.

If you test $\{\lnot, \land\}$ for each of the criteria you will notice that they meet the requirements for the theorem and are therefore (minimally) functionally complete.